# vmware server 2.0.2 error opening the remote virtual machine hostIP:8333/32

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, vmware-server

I have installed vmware server 2.0.2 on CentOS 6.2. I hit the issue **Error opening the remote virtual machine 192.168.1.91:8333\32: A connection to the host could not be established** when powering on a virtual machine and opening VMware Remote Console. (where 192.168.1.91 is the eth0 address of the host machine)

After some googling, I found a common solution is to either set up static IP or point to dns server to 127.0.0.1. But I'm not quite sure what it means.

Here is what I've tried.

- add `127.0.0.1 192.168.1.91` to my `/etc/hosts` file
- change domain-name-server in `/etc/vmware/vmnet1/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf` to 127.0.0.1 (so I use Host-Only for my virtual machine)
- add `nameserver 127.0.0.1` to my `/etc/resolv.conf`

None of the above works.

I've spent hours of time on the issue and really want to get it over with.

Please clarify it for me . Thanks.

Comment: Spend a few bucks and pick up a copy of Vmware Workstation.  Go with ESXi if the host is purely for VMs and has supported hardware.  Or use virtualbox/kvm/xen/etc.   Vmware Server is dead.

Comment: @Zoredache  the host is not purely for VMs. Also, I have to log on it via a jump machine or access web ui through socks proxy, which means no GUI is available. So which product would you recommend in my situation?

Answer (score 4):

Oh, easy.

[Don't install new instances of VMWare server, and migrate off any VMWare Server instances you do have now](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html).

> In January 2010, VMware announced the End of Support for VMware Server with support ending on June 30, 2011. Users are free to continue using VMware Server but are recommended to migrate to another VMware offering to gain the benefits of newer technologies.
>
> There are several VMware offerings that can replace VMware Server depending on the functionality needed. These offerings range from VMware Player for running one or two virtual machines to VMware vSphere Hypervisor for virtualizing on physical host, to VMware vSphere for running more than 100 virtual machines with centralized management and cloud scalability. See the Compare tab for a comparison of the offerings.

Replace Server with Player or ESXi (there's a free version), then try to set up virtual machines and virtual networking and all that.

Comment: Smart alec answer, but doesn't answer the question.  The product in question didn't just stop working overnight, just because they don't support it doesn't mean people still can't be helpful.

Comment: @JamesRyan Do it right, or don't do it at all.  There's absolutely no way you can slice it where installing VMWare Server is "doing it right" now that it's EOS.  Honestly, helping someone blow their foot off isn't what most reasonable folks would consider helpful.

Comment: It is not faulty, its simply not being updated anymore.  Sorry but there are many cases where you want to be compatible with other vmware products but need a base OS on a machine where it is entirely appropriate to still use it.  What is 'right' is merely your opinion and that is not what stackexchange is here for.

Comment: @JamesRyan Fine, install Windows 3.11 on all the things.  `It is not faulty, its simply not being updated anymore.`  Must be an appropriate solution to suggest on a StackExchange Site for [`Information Technology Professionals`](http://serverfault.com/faq), right?

Comment: Windows 3.11 does not host virtual machines, it would not be any use in this instance.

Comment: I still have VMware Server 2.0 installations on EL5.x servers... but I would *never* install it on a new or *modern* system. Right now, your best options are VMware Player or KVM (or maybe LXC if the guests are Linux)... The VMware compatibility argument is moot. The barriers to using ESXi are low, so if you need something that's VMware-like, use VMware.

Comment: `The product in question didn't just stop working overnight, just because they don't support it doesn't mean people still can't be helpful.` - Given that Vmware heavily depends on various kernel modules successfully compiling and working, it is perfectly reasonable to say that a kernel that is ~3 years newer then the last official release might just have breaking changes, which cannot be fixed.

Comment: 1 stable kernel version out of date, not exactly ancient history!

Answer (score 0):

Run vmware-config.pl.  And allow port 8333 in iptables.

Comment: Nice in theory.  My bet is that he is running a kernel new enough that the module compilation is failing.